# how to search File via search rest endpoint?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I'm trying to find a file via `/services/data/v41.0/parameterizedSearch` endpoint with body like this `{"q":"sps","sobjects":[{"name":"File"}]}` - it says that INVALID_TYPE, when I use name "Attachment" it finds **nothing**. Is it naming issue or I should use another endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried ContentDocument / ContentDocumentLink / ContentVersion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no object named as **FILE**, Files are stored as Attachment or ContentDocument.

Make sure you provide full name of file with extension.

eg:

```
{"q":"DL.jpg","sobjects":[{"name":"ContentDocument"}]}
```

Comment: thx, it works!!!